# Between the [tfs-vnext] and [vso-build] tag there is ambiguity

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

I originally created the tag [tfs-vnext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs-vnext) for the TFS 2015 vNext build functionality.

I recently came across the [vso-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vso-build) tag, which has a description that could also be applicable to the [tfs-vnext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs-vnext)  tag that I created.

The problem I see is that "VSO" means Visual Studio Online, and the new vNext build features are also available to stand-alone (non-hosted) installations.

Some suggestions:

- the vso-build should be re-purposed to only apply to "online" builds (and the description changed)
- questions tagged [vso-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vso-build) should be migrated to [tfs-vnext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs-vnext) to avoid implication that the question only applies to Visual Studio Online builds

Comment: @rene This is nowhere near a duplicate! The linked "duplicate" question purely pertains to Visual Studio online, whereas the tag [tfs-vnext] referenced in the question above is applicable to both the online, and on-site versions of Visual Studio. Further, this distinction is also spelled out in the question in the contrast between two two tags: " the new vNext build features are also available to stand-alone (non-hosted) installations".

Comment: I closed it as that duplicate because vso-build got added as a synonym to [vsts-build](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vsts-build/synonyms) which is what the dupe asked for, making none of your suggestions longer possible to execute. If that is wrong let me know.

Comment: @rene - Based on your description, your action was not wrong, but I think that merging tfs-vnext into vsts-build was wrong: it's possible to have a stand-alone version of TFS (on-site), which is not part of VSTS. vNext Build is a TFS feature, not just restricted to VSTS. Anyway, there was 0 interest in this post in the first place, so I'm not going to pursue it further. Thanks for the update.

Comment: It is unfortunate it happened this way but at least you now got notified and could assess the damage. If you change your mind on pursuing this  don't hesitate to ping me, we're working closely with the mod-team to evaluate all *tag* based meta posts, so it is easy to have someone look at it and check viability to turn things around.